# Getting text from a particular div class on a webpage HTML using VBA in excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

Edit: thank you for the solutions, guys.

The problem I have with the code below is the elements are not able to get the text under the div class **"col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-md-pull-6 col-lg-pull-7 p-main-title-wrapper"** from the webpage "https://www.racingandsports.com/thoroughbred/jockey/jake-bayliss/27461" and havge it print on the worksheet in excel. The only text that needs to be extracted is "JAKE BAYLISS" and nothing else.

```
Sub Horse6()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim node As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim nodeDiv As HTMLHtmlElement

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  r = 2
  c = 12
  
    With http
    .Open "GET", "https://www.racingandsports.com/thoroughbred/jockey/jake-bayliss/27461", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
  
'Problems with the elements are here

    With html.getElementsByClassName("np mainparent")
        For Each node In html.getElementsByClassName("col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5  col-md-pull-6 col-lg-pull-7  p-main-title-wrapper")
            For Each nodeDiv In node.getElementsByTagName("div")
              ws.Cells(r, c) = .Item(0).innerText
            Next
        Next
    End With
  
    MsgBox "Data input complete"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the method `getElementsByTagName()`. The desired text is in an `h1` tag, namely in the first one. The only line for direct access to it that you need is
`html.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innertext`

I have left out everything that is not needed for direct reading. You can see exactly that the whole loop construction is not necessary.

```
Sub Horse6()

Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
  
  With http
    .Open "GET", "https://www.racingandsports.com/thoroughbred/jockey/jake-bayliss/27461", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
  End With
  
  MsgBox html.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innertext
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting just the class 'p-main-title-wrapper' within your For Each selector? & also, rather than selecting the "div" in the second For Each try selecting the 'h1' element tag as it will be declared separately from the above elements.

Answer (score 0):

The code part you are speaking about looks like this

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-md-pull-6 col-lg-pull-7 p-main-title-wrapper">
    <h1 style="display:inline !important">JAKE BAYLISS</h1>
</div>
```

So you need to geth the `<h1>` tag inside that and not a `<div>` as you tried. See below:

```
Dim nodeH1 As HTMLHtmlElement
With html.getElementsByClassName("np mainparent")
    For Each node In html.getElementsByClassName("col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5  col-md-pull-6 col-lg-pull-7  p-main-title-wrapper")
        For Each nodeH1 In node.getElementsByTagName("h1")
          ws.Cells(r, c) = nodeH1.innerText
        Next
    Next
End With
```